# In Perl, how do you find the position of a match in a string, if forced to use a foreach loop? pos

Tags: perl, foreach

I have to find all the positions of matching strings within a larger string using a while loop, and as a second method using a foreach loop. I have figured out the while loop method, but I am stuck on a foreach method.  Here is the 'while' method:

....

```
my $sequence = 
   'AACAAATTGAAACAATAAACAGAAACAAAAATGGATGCGATCAAGAAAAAGATGC'.
   'AGGCGATGAAAATCGAGAAGGATAACGCTCTCGATCGAGCCGATGCCGCGGAAGA'.
   'AAAAGTACGTCAAATGACGGAAAAGTTGGAACGAATCGAGGAAGAACTACGTGAT'.
   'ACCCAGAAAAAGATGATGCNAACTGAAAATGATTTAGATAAAGCACAGGAAGATT'.
   'TATCTGTTGCAAATACCAACTTGGAAGATAAGGAAAAGAAAGTTCAAGAGGCGGA'.
   'GGCTGAGGTAGCANCCCTGAATCGTCGTATGACACTTCTGGAAGAGGAATTGGAA'.
   'CGAGCTGAGGAACGTTTGAAGATTGCAACGGATAAATTGGAAGAAGCAACACATA'.
   'CAGCTGATGAATCTGAACGTGTTCGCNAGGTTATGGAAA';

my $string = <STDIN>;
chomp $string;

while ($sequence =~ /$string/gi )
{
 printf "Sequence found at position: %d\n", pos($sequence)- length($string);
}
```

Here is my foreach method:

```
foreach  ($sequence =~ /$string/gi ) 

 printf "Sequence found at position: %d\n", pos($sequence) - length($string); 
}
```

Could someone please give me a clue on why it doesn't work the same way?
Thanks!

My Output if I input "aaca":

```
Part 1 using a while loop
Sequence found at position: 0
Sequence found at position: 10
Sequence found at position: 17
Sequence found at position: 23
Sequence found at position: 377

Part 2 using a foreach loop
Sequence found at position: -4
Sequence found at position: -4
Sequence found at position: -4
Sequence found at position: -4
Sequence found at position: -4
```

Comment: Using raw input `$string` in a regexp will act weird if somebody types in special characters (accidentally or maliciously).  Consider using `/\Q$string/gi` to avoid treating `$string` as a regexp.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem here is context.  In the `while` loop, the condition is in scalar context.  In scalar context, the match operator in `g` mode will sequentially match along the string.  Thus checking `pos` within the loop does what you want.

In the `foreach` loop, the condition is in list context.  In list context, the match operator in `g` mode will return a list of all matches (and it will calculate all of the matches before the loop body is ever entered).  `foreach` is then loading the matches one by one into `$_` for you, but you are never using the variable.  `pos` in the body of the loop is not useful as it contains the result after the matches have ended.

The takeaway here is that if you want `pos` to work, and you are using the `g` modifier, you should use the `while` loop which imposes scalar context and makes the regex iterate across the matches in the string.

Sinan inspired me to write a few `foreach` examples:

- This one is fairly succinct using `split` in separator retention mode:

  ```
  my $pos = 0;
  foreach (split /($string)/i => $sequence) {
      print "Sequence found at position: $pos\n" if lc eq lc $string;
      $pos += length;
  }
  ```
- A regex equivalent of the `split` solution:

  ```
  my $pos = 0;
  foreach ($sequence =~ /(\Q$string\E|(?:(?!\Q$string\E).)+)/gi) {
      print "Sequence found at position: $pos\n" if lc eq lc $string;
      $pos += length;
  }
  ```
- But this is clearly the best solution for your problem:

  ```
  {package Dumb::Homework;
      sub TIEARRAY {
          bless {
              haystack => $_[1],
              needle   => $_[2],
              size     => 2**31-1,
              pos      => [],
          }
      }
      sub FETCH {
          my ($self, $index) = @_;
          my ($pos, $needle) = @$self{qw(pos needle)};

          return $$pos[$index] if $index < @$pos;

          while ($index + 1 >= @$pos) {
              unless ($$self{haystack} =~ /\Q$needle/gi) {
                  $$self{size} = @$pos;
                  last
              }
              push @$pos, pos ($$self{haystack}) - length $needle;
          }
          $$pos[$index]
      }
      sub FETCHSIZE {$_[0]{size}}
  }

  tie my @pos, 'Dumb::Homework' => $sequence, $string;

  print "Sequence found at position: $_\n" foreach @pos; # look how clean it is
  ```

  The reason its the best is because the other two solutions have to process the entire global match first, before you ever see a result.  For large inputs (like DNA) that could be a problem.  The `Dumb::Homework` package implements an array that will lazily find the next position each time the `foreach` iterator asks for it.  It will even store the positions so you can get to them again without reprocessing.  (In truth it looks one match past the requested match, this allows it to end properly in the `foreach`, but still much better than processing the whole list)
- Actually, the best solution is still to not use `foreach` as it is not the correct tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks!  It is a lot to take in considering I have done about a week of Perl... but your answers are very helpful :D

Answer (score 2):

Eric's explanation of why `pos` will not work as intended in this context is spot on.

Now, if forced (I don't know by what authority ;-) to use a `for` loop, you can utilize the `index` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings; use strict;

my $sequence = <<EO_SEQ;
   AACAAATTGAAACAATAAACAGAAACAAAAATGGATGCGATCAAGAAAAAGATGC
   AGGCGATGAAAATCGAGAAGGATAACGCTCTCGATCGAGCCGATGCCGCGGAAGA
   AAAAGTACGTCAAATGACGGAAAAGTTGGAACGAATCGAGGAAGAACTACGTGAT
   ACCCAGAAAAAGATGATGCNAACTGAAAATGATTTAGATAAAGCACAGGAAGATT
   TATCTGTTGCAAATACCAACTTGGAAGATAAGGAAAAGAAAGTTCAAGAGGCGGA
   GGCTGAGGTAGCANCCCTGAATCGTCGTATGACACTTCTGGAAGAGGAATTGGAA
   CGAGCTGAGGAACGTTTGAAGATTGCAACGGATAAATTGGAAGAAGCAACACATA
   CAGCTGATGAATCTGAACGTGTTCGCNAGGTTATGGAAA
EO_SEQ

$sequence =~ s/\s//g;

my $string = <STDIN>;
chomp $string;

$string = uc $string;

for ( my $pos = 0; $pos >= 0; $pos = index($sequence, $string, $pos) ) {
    printf "Sequence found at position: %d\n", $pos;
    $pos += length $string;
}
```

Comment: for ≣ foreach && for(;;) ≣ while

Comment: @tchrist I like to write `for` everywhere, rather than `foreach`. As for `for(;;) ≣ while`, yes, point taken that the OP could have moved the `m//g` portion to the body of a `for(;;)` loop, but assuming a nonempty `for(...)`, this shows one way of how to replicate the functionality provided by using `while ( /.../g )` and `pos` together. I find it infinitely more preferable to stick with `while ( /.../g )`, leaving all equivalences aside.

Comment: I write `for` everywhere, too.

Comment: Thanks, I like your answer too!