# How to find position of a word by using a counter?

Tags: perl

I am currently working on a code that changes certain words to Shakespearean words. I have to extract the sentences that contain the words and print them out into another file. I had to remove .START from the beginning of each file.

First I split the files with the text by spaces, so now I have the words. Next, I iterated the words through a hash. The hash keys and values are from a tab delimited file that is structured as so, OldEng/ModernEng (`lc_Shakespeare_lexicon.txt`). Right now, I'm trying to figure out how to find the exact position of each modern English word that is found, change it to the Shakespearean; then find the sentences with the change words and printing them out to a different file. Most of the code is finished except for this last part. Here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use diagnostics;
use strict;

#Declare variables
my $counter=();
my %hash=();
my $conv1=();
my $conv2=();
my $ssph=();
my @text=();
my $key=();
my $value=();
my $conversion=();
my @rmv=();
my $splits=();
my $words=();
my @word=();
my $vals=();
my $existingdir='/home/nelly/Desktop';
my @file='Sentences.txt'; 
my $eng_words=();
my $results=();
my $storage=();

#Open file to tab delimited words

open (FILE,"<", "lc_shakespeare_lexicon.txt") or die "could not open        lc_shakespeare_lexicon.txt\n";

#split words by tabs 

while (<FILE>){ 
    chomp($_);
    ($value, $key)= (split(/\t/), $_);
    $hash{$value}=$key; 
}   

#open directory to Shakespearean files

my $dir="/home/nelly/Desktop/input"; 
opendir(DIR,$dir) or die "can't opendir Shakespeare_input.tar.gz";
#Use grep to get WSJ file and store into an array

my @array= grep {/WSJ/} readdir(DIR);

#store file in a scalar
foreach my $file(@array){

    #open files inside of input

    open (DATA,"<", "/home/nelly/Desktop/input/$file") or die "could not open $file\n";
    #loop through each file

    while (<DATA>){
        @text=$_;
        chomp(@text);
    #Remove .START
    @rmv=grep(!/.START/, @text);

foreach $splits(@rmv){
    #split data into separate words
    @word=(split(/ /, $splits));
    #Loop through each word and replace with Shakespearean word that exists
    $counter=0;

foreach $words(@word){
        if (exists $hash{$words}){
            $eng_words= $hash{$words};
            $results=$counter;
            print "$counter\n";
            $counter++;

#create a new directory and store senteces with Shakespearean words in new file called "Sentences.txt"
mkdir $existingdir unless -d $existingdir; 
open my $FILE, ">>", "$existingdir/@file", or die "Can't open       $existingdir/conversion.txt'\n";
#print $FILE "@words\n";

close ($FILE);

                }           
            }
        }
    }   
}

close (FILE);
close (DIR);
```

Comment: Could you post up some input data?

Comment: You lose some of the benefits of `my` by declaring the variables before it's needed. Also, all those assignments (except `my $existingdir='/home/nelly/Desktop'; my @file='Sentences.txt';`) are useless.

Comment: Most likely you are going to be using `index` `pos` and the like - as in this [similar SO question (take a look at the answers)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4856558/2019415). I don't know if you are setting up your lookup `%hash` correctly here though. Try using [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) or [`Data::Printer`](https://metacpan.org/release/Data-Printer) to look at how it is being filled in.

Comment: How are sentences stored in the file? It is one sentence per line? There are several issues with the Perl code, try adding `use warnings;` at the top and then resolving the warning messages.

Comment: Better to have `use warnings` rather than `-w`. Also, `DATA` is a special filehandle name to Perl, so you shouldn't use it for your own files. Current best practice is to use lexical variables for filehandles (`open my $in_fh, '<', $file_name or die $!`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Natural language processing is very hard to get right except in trivial cases, for instance it is difficult to define exactly what is meant by a *word* or a *sentence*, and it is awkward to distinguish between a single quote and an apostrophe when they are both represented using the `U+0027` "apostrophe" character `'`

Without any example data it is difficult to write a reliable solution, but the program below should be reasonably close

Please note the following

- `use warnings` is preferable to `-w` on the shebang line
- A program should contain as few comments as possible as long as it is comprehensible. Too many comments just make the program bigger and harder to grasp without adding any new information. The choice of identifiers should make the code mostly self documenting
- I believe `use diagnostics` to be unnecessary. Most messages are fairly self-explanatory, and `diagnostics` can produce large amounts of unnecessary output
- Because you are opening multiple files it is more concise to `use autodie` which will avoid the need to explicitly test every `open` call for success
- It is much better to use lexical file handles, such as `open my $fh ...` instead of global ones, like `open FH ...`. For one thing a lexical file handle will be implicitly closed when it goes out of scope, which helps to tidy up the program a lot by making explicit `close` calls unnecessary
- I have removed all of the variable declarations from the top of the program except those that are non-empty. This approach is considered to be best practice as it aids debugging and assists the writing of clean code
- The program lower-cases the original word using `lc` before checking to see if there is a matching entry in the hash. If a translation is found, then the new word is capitalised using `ucfirst` if the original word started with a capital letter
- I have written a regular expression that will take the next sentence from the beginning of the string `$content`. But this is one of the things that I can't get right without sample data, and there may well be problems, for instance, with sentences that end with a closing quotation mark or a closing parenthesis

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $lexicon      = 'lc_shakespeare_lexicon.txt';
my $dir          = '/home/nelly/Desktop/input';
my $existing_dir = '/home/nelly/Desktop';
my $sentences    = 'Sentences.txt';

my %lexicon = do {
  open my ($fh), '<', $lexicon;
  local $/;
  reverse(<$fh> =~ /[^\t\n\r]+/g);
};

my @files = do {
  opendir my ($dh), $dir;
  grep /WSJ/, readdir $dh;
};

for my $file (@files) {

  my $contents = do {
    open my $fh, '<', "$dir/$file";
    join '', grep { not /\A\.START/ } <$fh>;
  };

  # Change any CR or LF to a space, and reduce multiple spaces to single spaces
  $contents =~ tr/\r\n/  /;
  $contents =~ s/ {2,}/ /g;

  # Find and process each sentence
  while ( $contents =~ / \s* (.+?[.?!]) (?= \s+ [A-Z] | \s* \z ) /gx ) {
    my $sentence = $1;
    my @words    = split ' ', $sentence;
    my $changed;

    for my $word (@words) {
      my $eng_word = $lexicon{lc $word};
      $eng_word = ucfirst $eng_word if $word =~ /\A[A-Z]/;
      if ($eng_word) {
        $word = $eng_word;
        ++$changed;
      }
    }

    if ($changed) {
      mkdir $existing_dir unless -d $existing_dir;
      open my $out_fh, '>>', "$existing_dir/$sentences";
      print "@words\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped ALOT. I really appreciated how you pointed out my weak areas as well!!

Comment: @Borodin I have a little trouble fully grokking the OP's intent.  However, it sounded like they actually wanted to rebuild sentence structure.  If that's the case, then a regex solution seems more appropriate instead of splitting by spaces. `s{(\w+)}{ ... }eg`.  Nice job on the educating btw.