# How can I find _all_ locations of a regex match in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I can see from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856423/in-perl-how-do-you-find-the-position-of-a-match-in-a-string-if-forced-to-use-a) answer that if I do

```
sub match_all_positions {
    my ($regex, $string) = @_;
    my @ret;
    while ($string =~ /$regex/g) { push @ret, $-[0] }
    return @ret
}

print join ',', match_all_positions('0{3}', '001100010000');
```

I get

```
4,8
```

What do I need to do to get the indexes of *all* matches, even when the overlap, such as positions 8 and 9 in the example above?

I can do

```
sub match_all_positions_b  {
    my ($substr, $string) = @_;
    return unless index($string, $substr) > 0;
    my @res;
    my $i = 0;
    while ($i <= (length($string) - $length)) {
        $i = index($string, $substr, $i);
        last if $i < 0;
        push @res, $i++;
    }
    return @res;
}

print join ',', match_all_positions_b('000', '001100010000');
```

which just lets me match a substring, or

```
sub match_all_positions_c {
    my ($substr, $string) = @_;
    my $re = '^' . $substr;
    my @res;
    for (0..(length($string) - $length)) {
         push @res, $_ if substr($string, $_) =~ /$re/;
    }
    return @res;
}

print join ',', match_all_positions_c('0{3}', '001100010000');
```

Which is twice as slow.

is there a way to get *all* matches, even when they overlap? Or should I just take the speed loss because it's inherent to using regex matches?

Comment: Some sample data would be useful. The standard 'trick' for overlapping matches is zero width assertions.

Comment: @Sobrique - for data see the code examples. `match_all_positions('0{3}', '001100010000');` should return `(4, 8, 9)`; `match_all_positions('2{3}', '001100010000');` should return `()`;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to update your regex for [zero-width look-ahead](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) matching.

Try calling your function like this:

```
print join ',', match_all_positions('(?=0{3})', '001100010000');
```

Comment: it works. Now I just gotta read the docs and figure out why. Thanks! And it's blazing fast too.

Comment: It's because normally regular expressions _consume_  and so a match removes submatches from the pool. Zero width doesn't consume, it 'puts stuff back' to be reused.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the positions at which it matches:

```
my @matches;
push @matches, "$-[1]:$+[1]" while "aabbcc" =~ /(?=(a.*c))/sg;
```

Output:

```
0:6
1:6
```

---

If you want all possible matches,

```
local our @matches;
"aabbcc" =~ /(a.*?c)(?{ push @matches, "$-[1]:$+[1]" })(?!)/s;
```

Output:

```
0:5
0:6
1:5
1:6
```

Comment: Very nice indeed - but requires some thinking :-)